# How to submit `react-hook-form` properly with a `react-query` mutation?

Tags: react-hook-form, react-query

I use `react-query` in combination with `react-hook-form`. In order to activate the `isSubmitting` prop on form and show loading state while submitting, the mutate function needs to return a Promise instead of using `mutate` directly.

For now my workaround is as follows:

```
const { mutate } = useMutation(...);

const update = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      mutate(data, {
        onSuccess: resolve,
        onError: reject,
      });
    });
};
```

and then pass `update` to `methods.handleSubmit` comming from form.

Could anyone share some experience on this topic?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

> In order to activate the isSubmitting prop on form and show loading state while submitting, the mutate function needs to return a Promise instead of using mutate directly.

seems like this is a requirement of react-hooks-form?

You can use `mutateAsync`, which will return a Promise, and pass that to `react-hook-form`

Other than that, `useMutation` also returns an `isLoading` state for your mutation, so you could let react-query handle that (I don't know react-hooks-form, so not sure if that's possible).

Comment: `form.handleSubmit(myMutation.mutateAsync)` worked for me! This should be accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to `await` `mutateAsync`, then all worked fine in `react-hook-form`

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'd advise anyone to have a look at this great article to understand the difference between mutate and mutateAsync and the required error handling for the latter. https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#mutate-or-mutateasync

Answer (score 0):

simply use following code

```
const {register , handleChange , Errors} = useForm();

const {mutation , mutationAsync , isLoading , isError} = useMutation(postData);

const Submit = (data) => {
mutateAsync(data);
}

return(
<form onSubmit={handleChange(Submit)}>
<input type="text" register={'name'}/>
</form>
)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. When submitting an answer, please try to explain why and how your code works, as well as any links to other resources.